# How to use NSEvent using AppleScript on Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, applescript, appdelegate, nsevent

[NSEvent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqPlH.png)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent

```
set var1 to current application's NSEvent's pressedMouseButtons()
say var1

set var1 to current application's NSEvent's buttonNumber()
say var1
```

First one works, but second one doesn't work, how to solve it?

[AppDelegate main:]: +[NSEvent buttonNumber]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fffb09df330 (error -10000)

Comment: "Accessibility Inspector" should help you to choose appropriate property of any controls you want.

Answer (score 1):

- `pressedMouseButtons` is a **class** property.
- `buttonNumber` is an **instance** property, to be called on an instance.

You need to create an event or receive an event to be able to use `buttonNumber`